# Error namespace when load devtools library

Tags: r, namespaces, devtools

I got this error when loading devtools library

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’:
 package ‘fs’ does not have a namespace
```

I tried to manually install `devtools` and `fs` manually and it installed successfully but still cant load the library.

I am on windows 10, R version 3.5.3.

I use Rstudio.

Thank you

Comment: What versions of these packages do you have installed? Or how did you install `fs`? Seems like you might have installed an old version.

Comment: I installed it from CRAN I assumed that is the latest? its version 1.2.7

Comment: That should be the lastest. Does `library(fs)` run without error? Is your devtools from CRAN as well?

Comment: actually no! I just installed ``fs`` again and load library and it said 
Error in library(fs) : ‘fs’ is not a valid installed package

Comment: I figured out that i got 2 libpaths(), and i can load devtools using 
``library("devtools", lib.loc=.libPaths()[-1])`` with no error

Comment: Sounds like you have two versions of that package in different libraries.